# Java Program for Displaying Numbers in Array 1 not in Array 2

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking to make a code that will display unique numbers in array x not in array y. This is what I have so far. What am I doing wrong?

```
    int unique=0;
    int i,j,k;  
    int x[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int y[]={1,3,5,7,9};

    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<y.length;j++)
      {
         if(x[i] == y[j])
         {
             unique = 1;
         }
      }
      if(unique == 0)
      {
          System.out.print(x[i]);

          unique =0;
      }

}
```

The code is producing 000011111222233334444.

Comment: you have to reset the unique value, if not, once you get unique=1, it always keep the same value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should reset the unique value. So just add **`unique = 0;`** at the endo of the first loop:

```
int unique = 0;
int i, j, k;
int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int y[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
        if (x[i] == y[j]) {
            unique = 1;
        }
    }
    if (unique == 0) {
        System.out.print(x[i]);
        unique = 0;
    }
    unique = 0;
}
```